# Remove surrounding quotes json file, numbers only, php preg_replace

Tags: php, json, numbers, preg-replace, double-quotes

Discover some solutions in C or other languages but at no use at php.

I need to replace all numbers in a (large) json file to avoid numbers will be seen as string when used in javascript.

for example:

```
[["Alt","128","36.00","36.00","test" .....]]
```

What I want:

```
[["Alt",128,36.00,36.00,"test" .....]]
```

Have tried several things but I'm **not a preg expert**, something like this doesn't work:

```
$sOutput = preg_replace('/^(\'[0-9]\'|"([0-9])")$/', '$2$3', $sOutput );
die( $sOutput );
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$re = '/\"([0-9.]+)\"/m';
$str = '[["Alt","128.12","36.00","36.00","test" ....., "123.45"]]';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```